# Firewall rule visualisation tool

Tags: firewall, visualization

I am looking for tools that offer firewall visualisation. Google suggests [fwbuilder](http://www.fwbuilder.org/), but to my understanding its visualisation is only a slightly improved table.

EDIT: here's what I had in mind. This is done with basic graphviz. [image: A directed graph visualisation]

Comment: what kind of firewall do you plan on installing/manage? And what OS do you use as a client?

Comment: have you looked at fwbuilder and it doesn't do want you want?  if so, what type of visualization are you looking for?

Comment: OS doesn't matter, firewall types almost don't matter, but cisco pix and checkpoint fw would be the first choices. I am looking to get a graph out of it. I've looked at fwbuilder and sceenshots don't impress me.

Comment: hmm, what kind of graph ?

Comment: A directed one :) What is permitted to connect to what, very visually.

Comment: How does OS/firewall type not matter? If you're looking for something that takes a ruleset and generates a graph, it will need to support the ruleset format that you're using...

Answer (score 2):

Try http://jekor.com/gressgraph/

Comment: This certainly is in the direction that I want, but I've previously looked at it and found it too simple to graph more than say 100 or so rules - the visual clutter is visible even in the screenshot. But thank's for reminding nonetheless!

Comment: I'd say that GV isn't really up to the task to automatically layout huge graphs in a sane way - we all know of the algorithmic problems here. I'd suggest using gressgraph and then manually edit/layout to have some usable results.